# Why does the remove method not work as intended?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, range

I am trying to create a program that will spit out a list of numbers that are divisible by a **divisor**, in a certain range specified by **start** and **stop**. The code below does not work as intended. For example: supplying values start = 1, stop = 10, divisor = 3 returns this list: [2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9] I do not understand why... 2, 5, and 8 should not pass the number % divisor != 0 test, as it evaluates to True. Can someone explain please? Thank you :)

```
start = int(input("START: "))
stop = int(input("STOP: "))
divisor = int(input("DIVISOR: "))
if divisor <= 0:
    print("Cannot divide by zero")
else:
    user_numbers = list(range(start, stop + 1))
    for number in user_numbers:
        if number % divisor != 0:
            user_numbers.remove(number)
    print(user_numbers)
```

Comment: Why are you trying to remove from a list while iterating over it?

Comment: Because I am a noob? Can you please explain how that breaks the code?

Comment: Changing the size of the list causes the index of the loop to skip over elements

Comment: Thank you! Thats the answer I needed, I did notice it skips over some elements, I did not understand why that happens..

Comment: Just to note, you can divide by number *less* than zero. You might still want to skip them for this program, but the error message is inaccurate in that case :)